# Mostrar imágenes guardadas en storage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Como puedo mostrar en una tabla mis imagenes guardas en storage/app/public/

En la base de datos guarde la url de la imagen

```
<td><img src="{{ asset('storage/app/public/imgHabitaciones/', $hab->hab_urlimg )}}"></img></td>
```

No me muestra la imagen.

Answer (score 2):

Asumiendo que tengas el nombre correcto almacenado en `$hab->hab_urlimg`, con una pequeña modificación en la ruta debería funcionar, simplemente indicando `storage`:

```
<img src="{{ asset("storage/imgHabitaciones/$hab->hab_urlimg" )}}" alt="" />
```

Comment: disculpa para yo también aprender, ¿por qué ese cambio en que afecta?

Comment: Normalmente deberías crear un enlace simbólico (un comando artisan lo hace de hecho) cuando trabajas con el disco público, de `public/storage` a `storage/app/public`. En la documentación encuentras más información https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem#configuration

Comment: Ya no me marca error, y me muestra esta ruta en la herramientas de desarrollador: src="http://localhost:8000/storage/imgHabitaciones/1520272211_logo.png"
pero no me muestra la imagen, solo aparece la celda en blanco.

Comment: gracias me pondré a revisar

Comment: me lanza esto en la consola:
GET http://localhost:8000/storage/app/public/imgHabitaciones/logo.png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: ¿Tienes el enlace simbólico que señalé en un comentario más arriba?

Comment: Lo estaba haciendo, pero al momento de ingresar: php artisan storage:link no me deja avanzar y me manda el siguiente error:
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
  There are no commands defined in the "storage" namespace.
No se si sea por que tengo laravel 5.2

Comment: Exacto, dicho comando existe desde Laravel 5.3, pero puedes hacer el enlace simbólico manualmente.

Answer (score 0):

Este es un ejemplo de como se puede subir una imagen y como descargarlo.
Lo primero es configurar el archivo **../config/filesystems.php**.

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path().'/storage',//path que depende de donde quieran guardarlo
    ],
    //puede haber mas contenido aqui
],
```

Podrian subir una imagen en el storage de algun controlador:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $img=new ImagenEnDataBase();
    $file = $request->file('imagen');
    $nombre =  $file->getClientOriginalName();//depende de como lo nombren
    \Storage::disk('local')->put($nombre,  \File::get($file));
    $img->imagen_nombre=$nombre;// solo alamceno el nombre en la base de datos
    $img->save();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Ahora pasamos a descargarlo atravez de una ruta

**Ej:** teniendo una ruta en nuestro archivo `web.php`

`Route::get("getImage/{nombre}",'ImagenController@descargar');`

La funcion descargar seria la siguiente:

```
public  function descargar($nombre){
    $public_path = public_path();
    $url = $public_path.'/storage/'.$nombre;// depende de root en el archivo filesystems.php.
    //verificamos si el archivo existe y lo retornamos
    if (\Storage::exists($nombre))
    {
        return response()->download($url);
    }
    //si no se encuentra lanzamos un error 404.
    abort(404);
}
```

Y descargarla desde una etiqueta `img` desde html:

```
<img src="{{url('/getImage/',$img->imagen_nombre)}}" class="img-responsive">
```

Espero que esto ayude en algo

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me lanza el siguiente error en la consola:
GET http://localhost:8000/getImage/1519839717_er-hotel.png 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: podrias mostrar como almacenas las imagenes, puede que desde ahi este algo mal

Comment: si claro, las guardo así:


$img = $request->file('hab_urlimg');
    $file_route = time().'_'.$img->getClientOriginalName();
    Storage::disk('imgHabitaciones')->put($file_route, file_get_contents($img->getRealPath() ));

    $hab->hab_urlimg = $file_route;

Comment: Bueno ahora mostra la configuracion de ('imgHabitaciones')

Comment: Es esto: 
  'disks' => [

        'imgHabitaciones' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public/imgHabitaciones'),
        ],

Comment: ok, podes probarlo cambiando el root por `'root' => public_path().'/storage',`, para que funcione la respuesta que puse, posterior pruebas subiendo y bajando una imagen

Comment: Probe subiendo y ahora no sube la imagen..

Comment: edite la respuesta haber si te sirve de algo

Comment: hice todo tal cual, pero al momento de mostrarla, es mediante un foreach, para que me muestre las imagenes de cada registro... pongo esto en la vista:
<td><img src="{{url('/getImage/', $hab->hab_urlimg)}}" class="img-responsive">
      </td>

pero aún así no me muestra nada

Comment: Pero si me guarda las imagenes, en esa ruta: que es dentro de: storage/app

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74114/discussion-between-shassain-and-estefania).

Answer (score 0):

Después de varias hora analizando encontré la solución, si estas en un hosting compartido y tienes varios sitios la solución es muy fácil solo debes configurar el cpanel entras a dominios y configuras el directorio raíz a la carpeta storage/app ejemplo **dominio.com.co/storage/app** y listo

por si editaron provider
use **Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider**; si colocaron código deben dejarlo como estaba vació

en el archivo index de la carpeta public

```
require __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';


$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/app.php';
```